# How to hide an image on blank form submission?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have an image that is kind of a spinner that is displayed to a user on submitting a form.

So in js.coffe I do something like this:

```
$('.button.save-btn.btn.btn-primary').click ->
    $('.loader').show()
```

And if the form fails validations and an error is shown, at that time I hide the same image, like this:

```
$('#error-box').show();
$('.loader').hide();
```

The spinner works fine when an error is encountered but now what if when the user is clicking on the submit button when the form is empty. How do I handle that event? Where exactly do I hide the spinner image in this case?
  I hope I explained my query properly, any help will be much appreciated. Thanx in advance:)

Comment: Wouldn't them submitting a blank form just be an example of "when an error is encountered", and therefore be handled by your existing approach?

Comment: Actually that is the problem, I am not using or displaying any sort of error box for it. It shows html5 default message on blank form submission.

Comment: Can you explain more about this "html5 default message"?  I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use coffee personally but in plain js you could check if the fields have a value before showing the spinning image:

```
$('.button.save-btn.btn.btn-primary').click(function(){
    var form_compiled = false;

    //iterate trough each input field
    $("#MyformID").find("input, textarea").each(function(){

        //check if input field has a value or is empty
        if ($(this).val() != ""){
            form_compiled = true;
        }
    })

    // and then show the image if at least a filed is filled
    if ( form_compiled == true){
        $('.loader').show()
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans but the issue with this is that I will have same problem when my form is partially filled by the user and all my fields on the form aren't compulsory fields. So in that case I will have to individually chk the required fields are blank or not which I guess will become inefficient. Please do let me know if you can find some other way to do this.Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

the code above works if the user fills at leas a field.
If you want to run the check on just some mandatory fields you could add them the class "required", for example, then run the js check on those classes:

```
$('.button.save-btn.btn.btn-primary').click(function(){
    var form_compiled = true;  << change initialization

    $("#MyformID").find(".required").each(function(){

        //check if input field is empty
        if ($(this).val() == ""){
            form_compiled = false; //set to false is a required field is empty
        }
    })
    if ( form_compiled == true){
        $('.loader').show()
    }
```

})